# Different GCC version in eclipse, what should I set?

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc

I have installed the latest gcc version, without overwriting the existing one, so now I have two differents gcc versions installed. My question is how do I set eclipse CDT (luna version) to use such version? I've tried by setting in project, properties, C/C++ Build environment and changing the path variable, but it doesn't work.

Specifically the problem I have is:

```
make all
Building file: ../main.cc
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cc"
g++: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I changed the path variable to point to the binaries of the the gcc version i've installed.

More Info:
The OS is Red Hat

Comment: It doesn't work I've already tried.

Comment: You should try looking at the "update-alternatives" command, it's the most convenient when dealing with several versions of GCC or similar pieces of software. ;-)

Comment: What do u mean by "update-alternatves" command?

Comment: Type "man update-alternatives". If you install your second version of GCC as an alternative, you can just switch from one to another with a single command without having to change any configuration in Eclipse or anywhere else. I use both GCC 6.1.1 and 4.8.4 like this.

Comment: I'm having a look.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://codeyarns.com/2015/02/26/how-to-switch-gcc-version-using-update-alternatives/) for instance.

Comment: There's a small issue, I can't use the "sudo" command because i'm not the admin of the system. Indeed I wanted my local installation and use that version. Is there any other way around?

Comment: Maybe try the second answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version). You should also update your question if someone else comes by.

Comment: The update-alternatives is far from perfect. In a team environment one can't be sure which compiler Eclipse will use.  well it's mostly for the indexer, given that in our case our makefile have the gcc version specified in them. What if you have multiple projet each requiring different version of gcc.  Using Neon for now, hopefull this is fixed in more recent version of Eclipse/CDT

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have set the "PATH" in "Environment Variables" correctly
("My Computer -> Properties ->Advanced Settings -> Environment Variables").

Open a cmd prompt and type
echo %PATH%

Verify if the required compiler path is set correctly.

Now restart the Eclipse Luna to get the changes fetched. (Sometimes a system restart is also required)

Comment: Are you talking about windows?

Comment: @user8469759 I am sorry, the question didn't spoke anything about the OS used. So I presumed it to be Windows. I have faced a similar issue in Windows and this resolution worked.

Comment: I added the additional info.